# How to solve referenceerror module is not defined

Tags: javascript, module, referenceerror, unpkg

I am trying to import [asva-js-password-package](https://github.com/MFernstrom/asva-js-password-package) client side as below

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@marcusfernstrom/asva-password@1.1.5/index.js"></script>
```

But I am getting a `referenceerror module is not defined` in the browser console. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't with this file alone.

The module have not been written in **es6** module style, but in **CommonJS**. If you want to import this file as is, it wont works unless you import a library that support this syntax (like [requireJS](https://requirejs.org/)).

Another solution can be to compile this file with a JS transpiler like [browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify) that will produce a file browser compatible.